# Code works with prototype.js but not jquery library

Tags: jquery, prototype

The following code works with prototype.js only, but does not work with jquery. How can I change this code so that it works with the latest version of jquery?

```js
var colors = [ 'feff35','fff600','ffe800','d0eb2c','aed14f','40aa48' ];
    
    colors.each(function (color) {
        $$('.color-picker-bg')[0].insert('<div class="square" style="background: #' + color + '"></div>');
    });
    
    $$('.color-picker-bg')[0].on('click', '.square', function (event, square) {
        background = square.getStyle('background');
        $$('.bg').each(function (backgroundx) {
            backgroundx.setStyle({ 'background': background });
        });
    });
```

```css
.square {
  width: 31.25px;
  height: 31.25px;
  float:left;
  cursor:pointer;
 text-align:center;
  }
.square:hover::before{font-family:FontAwesome;content:"\f111";color:#fff;line-height: 31.25px;font-size:12px}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
<div class="color-picker-bg"></div>
<div class="bg">content</div>
```

Comment: can you post your html code? or create jsfiddle?

Comment: i posted all. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle for you here:-

http://jsfiddle.net/amitthk/7qep68sr/

Basically on clicking any of the squares, the background color changes accordingly. I believe this is what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var colors = [ 'feff35','fff600','ffe800','d0eb2c','aed14f','40aa48','71cde3','08a6f5','007cba','c200ff','a700dc','8601b0','ff7365','ff044e','f40000','c3003d','ff8400','ff6c00','eea407','e68325','fffefe','f7f7f7','d1d1d1','000000' ];
var strDiv='';
$(colors).each(function (idx) {
  strDiv += '<div class="square" style="background: #' + colors[idx] + '">&nbsp</div>'
});
  $('.color-picker-bg').first().html(strDiv);
    
    $('.color-picker-bg:first-child').on('click', '.square', function (event) {
    var $square = $(this);

    background = $square.css('backgroundColor');
    $('.bg').each(function () {
        $(this).css('background', background);
    });
});
  });
```

```css
.bg{width:100%; height:40px; background-color:#fefefe;clear:both;float:left;border:solid 1px #ccc}
.color-picker-bg .square{width:40px; height:40px; border:solid 1px #cccccc;float:left}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div>
<div class='color-picker-bg'>
  
  &nbsp;
  </div>

 <div class="bg">
        &nbsp;</div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Croot that's well done! Cheers! .... Mine still fully covers the case though :-)  Can I set your edit as base if u don't mind?

Comment: thank you @croot can you look my second answer about making this with two or more elements. Thank you all and sorry i am new here.

Comment: Feel free @amitthk :)

Comment: @amitthk yes this is what i want but now i want to add more elements for example background and color how can fixed for this? 

<div class='color-picker-bg'></div>
 <div class="bg"></div>

and

<div class='color-picker-color></div>
 <div class="color"></div>

Comment: **ercan** sorry I was away. I think @Croot already answered your question regarding multiple instances above. His [js fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7qep68sr/18/) Have a great day!